# Number of ways to choose rows with inclusion condition

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, binary

I have a large collection of lists consisting of 1's and 0's, each list the same length. I call each list a row.

I want to know the number of ways to select rows such that their cumulative OR results in all 1's. In other words, the number of ways to choose rows where at least one 1 exists in each column somewhere.

I am having trouble doing this efficiently. Right now I am using inclusion exclusion. The number of ways to choose rows with at least one 1 in each column is equal to the number of ways to select any subset of rows minus the number of ways to select no 1's in a column, or all 0's.

But I am having trouble taking this all the way because it requires being able to efficiently determine which rows have 0's in specific indices.

Comment: Actually you have more difficulties than that. When you figure out how many ways there are to choose rows that all have 0 in a particular index, this may partially overlap the ways to choose rows that all have 0 in a different index. In fact, your problem perhaps may likely not be able to be solved in polynomial time (It may be NP-hard or #P-hard).

Comment: I'm going to try to show this is a hard problem, and post an answer if I succeed. If that goes nowhere, then I'll try to come up with a fast solution and post that. Note that if you assume your input is random (i.e. 0 and 1 are chosen independently at random in each spot, with certain fixed probabilities) you may be able to come up with an algorithm that is LIKELY to run fast (although not guaranteed). Kinda like quicksort. At the very least I would expect you could come up with an approximate answer quickly in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

I found this paper http://cs-people.bu.edu/evimaria/papers/kdd127-gionis.pdf which indicates that your problem is indeed #P-complete, (if you look at it as a set-cover problem, which is easy to do, your 0 and 1 just say whether the given index is in the subset encoded by the row, and you want to cover all indices with a choice of subsets, i.e. rows), and hence, although there may be some heuristics to speed up counting (I haven't done enough reading to see if there are), you most likely can't find a polynomial time algorithm to count your number of solutions. The paper indicates some statistical approximation approaches though.

Comment: For a collection that contains every distinct patterns of 1's and 0's, the number of subsets who's union gives all 1's is identified by integer sequence A000371

Comment: @JohnMcGee That's a very interesting observation. Has there been any progress coming up with either closed-form formula or tractable recursive formulas for these numbers, when all possible sequences are considered?

Comment: You may want to check this reference, linked from the OEIS, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X73901416